# Parsing a Formal Logic in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I have the following language I am trying to parse.

```
formula ::=  true  
         |  false  
         |  var  
         |  formula & formula  
         |  ∀ var . formula
         |  (formula)

    var ::=  letter { letter | digit }*
```

I have been following [this article](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsing_a_simple_imperative_language) on the Haskell wiki and have used Parsec combinators to create the following parser.

```
module LogicParser where

import System.IO
import Control.Monad
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Expr
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Language
import qualified Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Token as Token

-- Data Structures
data Formula = Var String
             | TT
             | FF
             | Con Formula Formula
             | Forall String Formula
               deriving (Show)

-- Language Definition
lang :: LanguageDef st
lang =
    emptyDef{ Token.identStart      = letter
            , Token.identLetter     = alphaNum
            , Token.opStart         = oneOf "&."
            , Token.opLetter        = oneOf "&."
            , Token.reservedOpNames = ["&", "."]
            , Token.reservedNames   = ["tt", "ff", "forall"]
            }


-- Lexer for langauge
lexer = 
    Token.makeTokenParser lang


-- Trivial Parsers
identifier     = Token.identifier lexer
keyword        = Token.reserved lexer
op             = Token.reservedOp lexer
roundBrackets  = Token.parens lexer
whiteSpace     = Token.whiteSpace lexer

-- Main Parser, takes care of trailing whitespaces
formulaParser :: Parser Formula
formulaParser = whiteSpace >> formula

-- Parsing Formulas
formula :: Parser Formula
formula = conFormula
        <|> formulaTerm
        <|> forallFormula

-- Term in a Formula
formulaTerm :: Parser Formula
formulaTerm = roundBrackets formula
            <|> ttFormula
            <|> ffFormula
            <|> varFormula

-- Conjunction
conFormula :: Parser Formula
conFormula = 
    buildExpressionParser [[Infix (op "&" >> return Con) AssocLeft]] formula

-- Truth
ttFormula :: Parser Formula
ttFormula = keyword "tt" >> return TT

-- Falsehood
ffFormula :: Parser Formula
ffFormula = keyword "ff" >> return FF

-- Variable
varFormula :: Parser Formula
varFormula =
    do  var <- identifier
        return $ Var var

-- Universal Statement 
forallFormula :: Parser Formula
forallFormula = 
    do  keyword "forall"
        x <- identifier
        op "."
        phi <- formulaTerm
        return $ Forall x phi

-- For running runghc
calculate :: String -> String
calculate s = 
    case ret of
        Left e ->  "Error: " ++ (show e)
        Right n -> "Interpreted as: " ++ (show n)
    where 
        ret = parse formulaParser "" s

main :: IO ()
main = interact (unlines . (map calculate) . lines)
```

The problem is the `&` operator, I am trying to model it on [how the article parses expressions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsing_a_simple_imperative_language#Expressions), using the `Infix` function and passing it a list of operators and a parser to parse terms. However, the parser is not behaving as desired and I can't work out why. Here are some examples of desired behaviour:

```
true                         -- parsing -->      TT
true & false                 -- parsing -->      Con TT FF
true & (true & false)        -- parsing -->      Con TT (Con TT FF)
forall x . false & true      -- parsing -->      Con (Forall "x" FF) TT
```

However currently the parser is producing no output. I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: @mschmidt Thanks, I'll fix that.

Comment: When I try to parse, I get no output at all (I think it hangs/goes into an infinite loop). But if I remove `conformula` from the parser `formula` (i.e. if I do `formula =  formulaTerm <|> varFormula <|> forallFormula`), the parser works as desired.

Comment: Ok, I don't think, I _know_ it goes into an infinite loop (it slowed down my computer after a while). Here's the [output](https://i.imgur.com/vUtUBVb.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I managed to fix the problem by rephrasing the grammar, and conjunction is still left-associative:

```
formula :: Parser Formula
formula = conFormula
        <|> formulaTerm

formulaTerm :: Parser Formula
formulaTerm = roundBrackets formula
            <|> ttFormula
            <|> ffFormula
            <|> varFormula
            <|> forallFormula

conFormula :: Parser Formula
conFormula = 
    buildExpressionParser [[Infix (op "&" >> return Con) AssocLeft]] formulaTerm
```

This parsed the following successfully.
[image]

Comment: Looks OK for me, since it successfully parsed the `tt & ff & tt`. I never tried to use `buildExpressionParser`, but the trick is to parse for terms within the conjunction, not for formulas.

Comment: Since `conFormula` can already match a single `formulaTern`, you don't need `formulaTerm` as an alternative in `term`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is, that you try to parse a `formula` for which the first attempt is to parse a `formulaCon`. This then first tries to parse a `formula`, i.e. you create an infinite recursion **without consuming any input**.

To resolve this, you have to structure your grammar. Define your terms like this (note that all these terms consume some input before doing a recursion back to `formula`):

```
formulaTerm = ttFormula
          <|> ffFormula
          <|> varFormula
          <|> forallFormula
          <|> roundBrackets formula

forallFormula = do
  keyword "forall"
  x <- identifier
  op "."
  phi <- formula
  return $ Forall x phi
```

A formula is then either a single term or a conjunction consisting of term, an operator, and another formula. To ensure that all input is parsed, first try to parse a conjunction and - if that fails - parse a single term:

```
formula = (try formulaCon) <|> formulaTerm
```

Finally a `formulaCon` can be parsed like this:

```
formulaCon = do
  f1 <- formulaTerm
  op "&"
  f2 <- formula
  return $ Con f1 f2
```

The drawback with this solution is that conjunctions are now right associative.

Comment: I like this solution, although I'm not sure why we need a `try` for the `formulaCon`. I think I managed to fix it by rephrasing the grammar, preserving left-associativity. Could you take a look at it and check whether it's correct? I posted it as an answer.